# Express "success" or "throw exception" of Vavr Try in Java unit test

Tags: junit, vavr

I have a simple unit test which asserts on an object instance of `Try` from the vavr library.

```
@Test
public void testFoo()
{
    final Try<Foo> result = createMyFooInstance();

    assertThat(result.isSuccess()).isTrue();
}
```

My question focuses on the formulation of the test assertion.
Semantically I want to have "if foo is success, all fine, otherwise, throw the encapsulated exception". The latter one is important so that I can see the error cause directly in the JUnit output.

Is there any convenient API that I can use to nicely formulate that semantics?

Comment: You have no assertion in that test. You would need `assertThat(result.isSuccess()).isTrue()` to actually have an assertion. Asking for library recommendations is off-topic here.

Comment: You're right, I overlooked it. I do not get your point about library recommendations. I am asking whether the libraries AssertJ, Vavr and related allow me a nice formulation of the semantics. So I am not asking for a new library, but rather how to use them properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
@Test
public void testFoo() {
    final Try<Foo> result = createMyFooInstance();
    result.get();
}
```

In case when `result` is a `Failure`, `result.get()` will throw the wrapped exception. In case when `result` is a `Success`, it will succeed.

Though this solution doesn't contain explicit assertions, it will implicitly fail the cases when the `result` is a `Failure`.

If you prefer to have an assertion failed instead of a test failed with exception, you could also use:

```
@Test
public void testFoo() {
    final Try<Foo> result = createMyFooInstance();
    assertThatCode(result::get).doesNotThrowAnyException();
}
```

Comment: How about `assertThat(result.get()).isEqualTo(myExpectation);`? This will both throw if it was a failure, and allows you to assert of the success result. BTW that's what we do in my team.
Also, worth mentioning the recent assertj-vavr library, I see cool stuff like `shouldContain()` from https://github.com/assertj/assertj-vavr/blob/master/src/main/java/org/assertj/vavr/api/TryShouldContain.java

Comment: Yes, but according to the question they don't have anything to compare the result to. They just want to know if it's successful, and throw the original exception if not - that's essentially unwrapping the `Try` with `get()`.